# Animate Android UI Component (ImageView here) using thread.sleep()

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an android application in which i want to move a imageView frame-by-frame on the splash screen using the following code:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000); //giving a 2s wait
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    iv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, i*2); //increasing the bottom padding each 50ms
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

But this code blanks the screen for `(2000 + 100*50) milliseconds` and then displays the application with the final position of the image (ie no animation is shown).
How can i get the animation? Also, is there any UI library for android which can help me doing this in an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using thread,
use a handler:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){...RUNNING CODE GOES HERE....}, 2000)
```

Read more about why using handlers and not Threads here:
http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/androidupdate-ui-through-handler/